# How to launch atom live server step by step?

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

I am learning JavaScript from Scratch . The Instructor is using ATOM editor. I am not able to launch live server. Please suggest me steps.

Answer (score 7):

To install atom-live-server:

1. open Atom
2. under edit hit preferences
3. choose install
4. type atom-live-server in the search
5. click install

To launch atom-live-sever:

1. open your project folder on atom
2. under packages choose
   atom-live-server
3. click start server

Done.

Answer (score 3):

I had a same problem. When I used <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> shortcut, or followed instructions in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2gonGjHDDc), nothing really happened.

However, I solved it by restarting `atom-live-server` package:

1. go to Atom `Settings`,
2. click on `Packages`,
3. click on `Disable` button within `atom-live-server` card,
4. click on `Enable` button within `atom-live-server` card.

Now, when you use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> shortcut, live server will start. You can quit live server with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "live server"? Would you like to test website on your local network? If so, the easiest solution is (assuming you have node.js installed) to install `http-server` command-line tool. Install it globally with `npm install http-server -g`, then navigate (of course in terminal) to the directory where your website is and type `http-server` command. Message like this will appear:
`Starting up http-server, serving ./
Available on:
  http://192.168.1.6:8080
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server`

To launch your website on your machine or another machine on the same network, just go to http:// *ip* :8080

If you don't have node.js, Python also offers similar command-line tool. You can use it with:

- If Python version is 3.X `python -m http.server`
- If Python version is 2.X `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

Answer (score 0):

If atom live server is already installed, we can restart it by,
ctrl-alt-l 
link: https://atom.io/packages/atom-live-server

Answer (score 0):

If the atom live server is already installed, click Packages on the menu bar.

There will be a dropdown menu "atom-live-server", hit start